# How to change/re-write git history to include original versions of files, unavailable at time of git init

Tags: git

I have started using git to store unix config file changes.

If I start with a system that has already been configured I would like to add the original versions of the files from the distibution into the beginning of the git history so that I can neatly see the changes to these. I intend to reinstall each package on the system one-by-one to get the original config files; store them in git; restore my version of the config file (perhaps using git); then commit the changed version of the file.

Can git do this neatly?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have multiple problems:

- First, in order to track a file with git, you need to put it into a repository. Configuration files are scattered around your file system, so you cant just put them all into one repository.
- Second, some configuration files may change even if their content stays the same. Think of an .xml file that gets read and written again. The structure may have changed, even though it actually contains the same content.

Comment: 1) I am puting them in a repository, that part works file. 2) If a file changes, I want to know about it.

Comment: Then, you can do want you want to do. Just commit your current configs. Then you can reinstall/download/restore the default configs and commit them too. Rebase the commit with the current configs onto the default config commit. Check it out and you have your configs back.

Comment: Can you give a detailed example please. I am not getting the commands in the right order I think. I would like my diffs to show that I applied my changes to the default configs, rather than the other way around.